# How to .apply(lambda x: x.split()) on a partial dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am trying to replace this kind of answer in my data frame : `case_1 case_2 case_3`

by : `[case_1,case_2,case_3]`

.apply(lambda x: x.split()) seems to be a good way to do it

But I also have some Nan value in the dataframe that raise this error :
[image]

Does somebody have an idea how should I proceed ?
Maybe how to apply the function on the dataframe only if a value exist ?

```
    r_bt.res_enquete_poteaux['type_anomalie'].apply(lambda x: x.split() if x!=np.nan)
                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The missing values are considered like "float" objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) working also with missing values:

```
r_bt.res_enquete_poteaux['type_anomalie'].str.split()
```

Your solution is possible change with [`notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.notna.html) for test not missing values:

```
r_bt.res_enquete_poteaux['type_anomalie'].apply(lambda x: x.split() if pd.notna(x) else x)
```